# How to control the Windows Magnifier API out of a C# Form?

Tags: c#, forms, winapi

I try to control the Zoom level of the Windows Magnifier out of a C# Form, unfortunately i was not able to get sending the WindowsKey + (Num+) to work. Anyway my preferred solution would be to use the Magnifier API directly and initialize a full screen magnification and set a zoom level there. Although i could finde people doing similar things (for example [Magnification Windows API - How to add Smoothing/Anti Aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67988506/magnification-windows-api-how-to-add-smoothing-anti-aliasing) ) my limited knowledge prevented me from reconstruction working code out of it. If anyone can hint me into a direction of what i have to put into my C# code to initialize the magnifier and set a zoom, that would be a great help. Sorry for this unspecific question.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Iam_losing_my_mind_on_this
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       
        public Form1()    
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        } 

    void Magnifier()
    {
      //code that opens the full screen magnifier
      //and sets a zoom level 
     }
    }
}
```

Just a short representation of what i try to achieve, so far neither the internet, chatgpt nor Fiverr could help

Comment: [Magnification API sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Magnification).